# How to convert a Spark rdd containing np.array (or list) to a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How to convert a Spark rdd containing np.array (or list) to a Spark DataFrame?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Create a SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()

rdd = sc.sparkContext.parallelize(np.array([1.1,2.3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
print(rdd.collect())
#[1.1, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]

Schema = StructType([       
    StructField('name', ArrayType(FloatType(), True))])

spark_df = rdd.toDF(Schema)
spark_df.show()
```

```
[1.1, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
22/04/03 16:04:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/zenbook/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1398, in verify_struct
    raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 1.1 in type <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Note: I've removed some spark error logs for clarity.

I've tried with a list and get a pretty close error:

```
rdd = sc.sparkContext.parallelize([1.1,2.3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print(rdd.collect())
#[1.1, 2.3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Schema = StructType([       
    StructField('name', ArrayType(FloatType(), True))])

spark_df = rdd.toDF(Schema)
spark_df.show()
```

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 1.1 in type <class 'float'>
```

In “Learning Spark book(O'reilly)”, it's written ArrayType => List,Tuple or Array Python type.

Why I need to do that: I can't convert byte_array(hex) to float_array using Spark_DF (3 days trying this). I've converted them with Spark_rdd.

```
def get_msp(row):
    """ extract MSN from row as numpy array"""
    return np.frombuffer(row.MSP,dtype=np.float64) # or list adding .tolist()
spectra=df.rdd.map(format_value)
```

Maybe at the moment, converting a Spark_RDD with a list/array to a Spark_DF is not achievable?

Because I wish to use this array/list with SparkML (PCA and LLA), a solution with a VectorAssembler will be great too.

Comment: not so interoperable, do you need an RDD or list?

Comment: I got an RDD as input and I need to transform it to a Spark_DF in order to use SParkML suite.

Comment: Not sure that will work, can I convert to DF?

Comment: @thebluephantom sorry, I don't understand "can I convert to DF". Could you explain a bit more? Note: I wish to avoid sending data to the main node and stay distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numpy.float64` is not known to Spark's dataframes but you can convert the values in the rdd to floats with:

```
spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(lambda x: float(x)), FloatType())
```

Demo:

```
rdd.collect()
# [1.1, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]

# rdd datatypes are numpy.float64
rdd.map(lambda x: type(x)).collect() 
# [numpy.float64,
#  numpy.float64,
# . . . 
#  numpy.float64]

# create dataframe
spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(lambda x: float(x)), FloatType()).show()
# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# |  1.1|
# |  2.3|
# |  3.0|
# |  4.0|
# |  5.0|
# |  6.0|
# |  7.0|
# |  8.0|
# |  9.0|
# | 10.0|
# +-----+
```